# Steam bending American Walnut

Tags: skirting

We have a bay window which has an actual curve to it rather than the half octogan that some have.

We have skirting boarded the rest of the room in American Walnut and trying to determine how to bend it into a curve. The walnut has been pre-oiled.

I am not comfortable in kerf cuts as this is the only piece of remaining walnut that covers the span. If I ruin this piece then I will have to probably go with two pieces in the bay as it took several weeks to get this wood and carpet fitting is rapidly approaching.

Currently I have it suspended between two stacks of books which I am slowly loading with tubs of water to bend it.

I was thinking of raising it further off the floor, draping towels over the edges and putting a food steamer underneath and running it to aid/speed up the bending.

Will this aid me or is it likely to ruin the wood?

Comment: You may benefit from the experience on the Woodworking Stack.

Comment: @Solar Mike Is cross posting in this instance okay?

Comment: Just state you posted on the other... And update with "I had a nice answer on this or that stack...)

Comment: I would also state the thickness of the board and how much bend you need.  I think you usually want a form to get the correct bend.

Comment: And need to allow for spring back.

Comment: The thickest edge is 20mm and the thinnest is 5mm.  The span is 2.5m and height is 150mm

Comment: Definitely see the woodworking stack. There are specific techniques for steam bending that you aren't using, judging by your description.

Comment: What's the approximate bend radius? My instinct is to table saw it into veneers and glue them at the radius. I assume you don't have enough material for the kerfs, though.

Comment: The bend is 12.6cm.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went with the food steamer placed under the board with weights placed in the middle. Eventually got to 18kg. Finally after removing from the weight it was left with 8cm of bend which will have to do as the carpet fitters are coming. Here is a photo of the early setup. Once the additional weight went on I had to raise the two stands with more books as the towel was resting on the back of the steamer.

[image]